# Returning pass data from Background.html to popup.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've passed data from the background to the popup fine. However, if I return `response.reply` I get undefined but if I print it out, its not undefined. It's as I expected it to be. How do I return this?

**popup.html**

```
function getURL(action){
    chrome.extension.sendRequest(
            {
                req: "geturl",
                act: action
            },
                function(response)
                {
                    return response.reply;
                });
            }
```

**background.html**

```
function getURL(action)
{
    var url = cmshttp+cmshooksurl+"?action="+action;
    return url;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return a value from asynchronous function. You need to pass the value to the next function instead (callback).

You code should look like this:

```
function getURL(action, callback){
    chrome.extension.sendRequest(
            {
                req: "geturl",
                act: action
            },
                function(response)
                {
                    callback(response.reply);
                }
    );
}
```

Usage:

```
getURL("some_action", function(reply) {
    console.log("reply is:", reply);
});
```

background.html:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.req == "geturl") {
        sendResponse({reply:"reply from background"});
    }
});
```

Comment: when I attempt this I get a `undefined` is not a function error.

Comment: @Skizit I just tried it and it works. Can you show your background page maybe?

Comment: @Skizit Are you expecting `getUrl()` function from background page to be called automatically? You need to listen to requests using  `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener`

Comment: I have that already setup. I'm sure all of the background is w0rking I can bring the value in the `function(response)` part in popup.html. Code is dying on `callback(response.reply)`.